# How to install OpenErp 7 on a Shared Server

Tags: installation, odoo

i have a server with Postgree Sql + Python support but i can't access to it through SSH.

I just can use ftp to upload the files. There is not OpenErp installation through the web? Do i need to buy a dedicated server so i can use ssh to launch the instalation commands?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think without ssh you are stuck. Depending on the shared servers support for WSGI, it may be possible but I would think as soon as you hit a problem you will be in trouble.

Rackspace and linode have reasonable VPS servers that will do the job. I have used both of these in the past for other uses and found them fine but there are loads of VPS providers out there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hosting service that is already adapted to work with OpenERP, like [My ERP Engine](https://www.myerpengine.com/). It directly install OpenERP and allows to modify it using a SSH connection.